# handle NULL case inside sqlArgToJava of custom persister class

Tags: java, javafx-8, ormlite

I'm using ormlite in one of my projects and I have a class `A` with a field `f` of custom type `F` and I have the requirement that field `f` should not be null in any case. So I want to instantiate a new object of class F whenever the field f is NULL in the database file

```
class A {
    @DatabaseField(columnName = "xyz", persisterClass = FieldPersister.class)
    F f;

    public A() {
        f = new F();
    }
}
```

As per the docs I using a custom persister class `FieldPersister` and attempting a null check in there.

```
class FieldPersister extends StringType {
    public Object javaToSqlArg(FieldType fieldType, Object javaObject) {
        ...
    }

    public Object sqlArgToJava(FieldType fieldType, Object sqlArg, int columnPos) {
        if (sqlArg == null) return new F();
        else {
            String value = (String) sqlArg;
            return new F(value);
        }
    }
}
```

I tried debugging the program and saw that there is already a null check in the following method

```
resultToJava(FieldType fieldType, DatabaseResults results, int columnPos)
```

Even overriding this method didn't resolved the issue which leads to my question, is there any way to handle this situation or am I missing some part of the puzzle?

Update with SSCCE:

[pom.xml](http://pastebin.com/ZEE4HSPn)

[Main.java](http://pastebin.com/edX3m8Yy)

[StringPropertyPersister.java](http://pastebin.com/hyuD3bXy)

Comment: I have updated the post with a test program, see if it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Even overriding this method didn't resolved the issue which leads to my question, is there any way to handle this situation or am I missing some part of the puzzle?

You are missing a part of the puzzle and it's pretty subtle.  Unfortunately the the `ResultSet.getInt(...)` method returns an `int`.  Why does this matter?  Because ORMLite can't tell if the field in the database is `NULL` or not if it is a primitive.  So typically what happens is that ORMLite gets a result from the `ResultSet`, asks it to be converted by the custom converter, and then ORMLite sees if it is null and adjusts the value appropriately.  Maybe there are better ways to do that.  I'll need to think about it.

You have a couple of solutions here.

1. Add a `defaultValue = ""` to the definition of your field.  This won't handle the case if there is `NULL` value on disk but it will work if you are using `dao.create(...)`.   You then can use `FieldConverter.parseDefaultString(...)` to define your default object to insert if the field is null.
2. In your `A.getValue()` method, you do the `null` check there and return a `new SimpleStringProperty("")` if it is null.  But then your example code maybe be  overly simplistic.
3. The hack is to override both the `resultToJava(...)` method to be something like:

   ```
   @Override
   public Object resultToJava(FieldType fieldType, DatabaseResults results,
           int columnPos) throws SQLException {
       // remove the null check here so we can handle the null
       Object value = resultToSqlArg(fieldType, results, columnPos);
       return sqlArgToJava(fieldType, value, columnPos);
   }
   ```

   But you also need to override the following which is a hack.

   ```
   @Override
   public boolean isStreamType() {
       // this forces the null check to be ignored
       return true;
   }
   ```

   This is a hack because if ORMLite subtly changes the way it handles "stream" SQL types, it might break your code.

   See my version of your test here: [CustomFieldNullTest.java](https://github.com/j256/ormlite-core/blob/master/src/test/java/com/j256/ormlite/field/CustomFieldNullTest.java).

Comment: Thanks! it worked. I used the 3rd solution as I already have `NULL` stored on disk.